# How to set See More and See Less content button to right side of the last line of TextformField in flutter

Tags: flutter, textformfield, flutter-textformfield

I want Textformfield functionality like besides the last line of textfoemfield there should be one textbutton called seemore and seeless. firstly textformfield will have initial value and  have set the maxline up to 10 if user tap on seemore it will expand and button text will be now see less. if user tap on see less it will set max line up to 10

i have used this code but this is not i wanted.

```
                 Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      cursorColor: Colors.white,
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                                      obscureText: false,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                        textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: 
                                        AppColors.white),
                                      ),
                                      controller: descriptionController,
                                      maxLines:showMoreScript==true? null:10,
                                      minLines: 1,
                                      textCapitalization: 
                                 TextCapitalization.sentences,
                                      onChanged: (text){
                                        _update();
                                      },
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        counterText: '',
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                        hintText: 'Write your script here',
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Calibri', 
                                        fontSize: 16, color: AppColors.formGrey),
                                        border: InputBorder.none,

                                      ),
                                      validator: (value){
                                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                          return 'Write your script here';
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Visibility(
                                    visible: true,
                                    child: Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: (){
                                            setState(() {
                                              showMoreScript = !showMoreScript;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Text("Show More",style: 
                                       GoogleFonts.poppins(textStyle: 
                                       TextStyle(color: AppColors.buttonRed,fontSize: 
                                       15)))),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

The current result:[image]

Expected result : [image]

Comment: Are you sure the text is in TextFormField? Seems like a normal text widget

Comment: yes i am using textformfield. and i want this feature in textforfield

Answer (score 0):

This seems like textview not textformfield
if you just want to show text not make it editable.
you can use this package: [expandable_text](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_text) from pub.dev

Comment: thank you but i want to do it with textformfield.